# MongoDB: Delete 'orphaned' documents?

Tags: mongodb, join, orphan

I am trying to delete orphaned documents in mongodb, which cross collections.
In the collection 'values', I have documents like this:

```
value:
{
   resultId: <ObjectId>
   ...other data..
}
```

which reference documents in the collection 'results':

```
result:
{
   _id: <ObjectId> //the resultId
}
```

A number of 'result' documents have been deleted, resulting in orphaned 'value' documents. How can I find all orphans and delete them?

Answer (score 2):

What you will want to do is build up an aggregate pipeline and use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator  to fetch the corresponding result document. Then, add a `$match` operator to your aggregate pipeline to filter those that don't have corresponding result object.

```
db.values.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "results",
      localField: "resultId",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "resultDocument"
    }
   },
   { $match: { resultDocument: {$size:0} }}
])
```

This way, you have identified your orphaned documents and can delete them afterwards.